# How to get ride of running "sudo swapoff -a" command everytime before running "kubectl" commands?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

It seems I must run `sudo swapoff -a` command everytime I want to run `kubectl` commands because if I don't do that it gives me such a following error:

```
The connection to the server 192.168.1.2:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Is there a way to do that permanently and getting ride of always running `sudo swapoff -a` command?

Comment: Do you have enabled the swap to the kubernetes Master nodes and worker nodes?
If I remember correctly, one of k8s installation requirements is to disable the swap to the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable the swap to a Linux machine, you have to elevate with root and edit `/etc/fstab`.
From there, remove the swap entry by commenting it out. 
Upon reboot, swap will not mount.

Comment: I have done this before but still my Kubernetes doesn't work.

Comment: ok. can you post your ```cat /etc/fstab``` and ```df``` outputs before do ```swapoff -a``` ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is not only related to the swapfile.

It comes also as soon you join an additional node and you dont have a network fabric installed.

Like flannel https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel